# i cannot deploy my app in heroku because of memory leak.connect.session()

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to deploy a Node.js app in Heroku but for some reason, the status of my app is changed from starting to up. it says that my      connect.session()
MemoryStore is not designed for a production environment, as it will leak memory and will not scale past a single process.

The main app

```
var express     =require('express');

 app        =express();
bodyParser  =require('body-parser');
mongoose    =require('mongoose');
passport    =require('passport'),
methodOverride=require('method-override');
customer    =require('./models/customer');
localStrategy=require('passport-local');
User        =require('./models/user');

//connects to database
// mongoose.connect(":mongodb://localhost/customerdb", {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://ajahi:himali@cluster0.rnubr.mongodb.net/mobilebanam? 
retryWrites=true&w=majority", {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(express.static(__dirname +('/public')));
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));

//passport configuration
app.use(require('express-session')({
secret:'pinte chor',
resave:false,
saveUninitialized:false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new localStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/',function(req,res){
res.render('home.ejs');
});
app.get('/confirmation',function(req,res){
res.render('confirmation');
})

app.get('/sathi',IsLoggedIn,function(req,res){
//get customer from db
customer.find({},function(err,customer){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
         //show it in the sathi page
        res.render('sathi',{friends:customer});
    }
});
//show it in the sathi page
});
app.get('/login',function(req,res){
res.render('login')
})
app.post('/login',passport.authenticate('local',
{
    successRedirect:'/sathi',
    failureRedirect:'/login'
}),function(req,res){
});
app.get('/register',function(req,res){
res.render('register');
});
app.post('/register',function(req,res){
User.register(new User({username:req.body.username}),req.body.password,function(err,user){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return res.redirect('/register');
    }
    passport.authenticate('local')(req,res,function(){
        res.redirect('/sathi')
    });
});
});
app.post('/sathiNaya',function(req,res){//create--------------
var name=req.body.name;//name input
var p=req.body.problem;// input problem
var c=req.body.contact;
var nc={name:name, problem:p, contact:c}//object of the input
//create a new customer and save to db
customer.create(nc,function(err,cutomer){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        res.redirect("/confirmation");//render of the list page
    }
})
});

app.delete('/delet/:id',function(req,res){
customer.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id,function(err){
    console.log(req.params.id)
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        console.log('succesfully deleted');
        res.redirect('back');
    }
})
})

app.get('/logout',function(req,res){
req.logout();
res.redirect('/');
})

function IsLoggedIn(req,res,next){
if(req.isAuthenticated()){
    return next();
}res.redirect('/login');
}
// app.listen(3000,function(req,res){
//     console.log('server is listening');
// });
app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP);
```

help this good fellow Samaritan in pointing out the obvious mistake.

Comment: Please post the complete log output with the error.